# Mysql. How to select Users from log table using two different text records

Tags: mysql, sql, database, logging, sql-optimization

I have a huge log table and I need to fetch some data for usage statistics.
let's say we have a log table:

```
| user_id | action            |
| 12345   | app: IOs          |
| 12345   | app_version: 2018 |
| 12346   | app: Android      |
| 12346   | app_version: 2019 |
| 12347   | app: Windows      |
| 12347   | app_version: 2019 |
```

Is there a way to fetch all user ids who uses old(2018) mobile apps?

There is a way I did it but it is not efficient

```
SELECT 
     user_id
FROM 
    log
WHERE 
    action LIKE '%2018%'
AND 
    user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM log WHERE(action LIKE '%IOs%' OR action LIKE '%Android%' ))
GROUP BY user_id
```

This query took about half an hour on production.

So in the end I want to have list of user ids as efficient as possible as I also will join another table to get their emails.
What options do I have?

Comment: Any EXPLAIN output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT l.user_id
FROM log l
WHERE l.action LIKE '%2018%' OR
      l.action LIKE '%IOs%' OR
      l.action LIKE '%Android%'
GROUP BY l.user_id
HAVING SUM(l.action LIKE '%2018%') > 0 AND       -- at least one 2018
       SUM(l.action LIKE '%2018%') <> COUNT(*);  -- at least one other
```

Unfortunately, the `LIKE` comparisons require scanning the `log` table.  The only way around this would be to use a full text index.

You can simplify the logic to:

```
SELECT l.user_id
FROM log l
WHERE l.action REGEXP '2018|IOs|Android'
GROUP BY l.user_id
HAVING SUM(l.action LIKE '%2018%') > 0 AND       -- at least one 2018
       SUM(l.action LIKE '%2018%') <> COUNT(*);  -- at least one other
```

I'm not sure if one `REGEXP` is (marginally) faster than three `LIKE`s or not.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I tried it but my initial query seems to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT l.*
FROM log l
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM log l1 WHERE l1.user_id = l.user_id AND l1.action LIKE '%2018%');
```

Comment: I've tried to run it, but it takes ages to run on my test system, so regardless of output it's much slower that my query.
But still, thank you for input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with a `LEFT JOIN`. I understand that you have a big logging table so this might not be the best one. I also added a few more records for testing:

Basically I use the `LEFT JOIN` to move data from columns to rows so that I can simply filter with `WHERE`.

SQL fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9db538e59b3d265e4e8d8559762e79d4

```
WITH log_table AS (
      SELECT *
      FROM (VALUES (12345, 'app: iOS'),
                   (12345, 'app_version: 2018'),
                   (12346, 'app: Android'),
                   (12346, 'app_version: 2019'),
                   (12347, 'app: Windows'),
                   (12347, 'app_version: 2019'),
                   (12348, 'app: iOS'),
                   (12348, 'app_version: 2019'),
                   (12349, 'app: Android'),
                   (12349, 'app_version: 2018'),
                   (12350, 'app: Windows'),
                   (12350, 'app_version: 2018')
           ) v(user_id, action)
)
SELECT 
    L.user_id
FROM 
    log_table AS L 
    LEFT JOIN log_table AS L2 
         ON L.user_id = L2.user_id
WHERE (L.action LIKE '%iOS%' OR L.action LIKE '%Android%') AND L2.action LIKE '%2018%'
```

The result: (only select those with iOS or Android and have 2018 version)

```
user_id
 12345
 12349
```

Comment: Am I right understood that you usung WITH clause to emulate data and in my case with real data I can just use select statment with my log table? 
If so, then it also takes a long time to run :(
Still, thank you for you help.

Comment: @Vladk Yeah you only need the SELECT part to run, and change the name of the table. You might want to try out Gordon's answer as he is much more experienced with SQL.